# iOS 10.3.1 : can't add a Google account to iPhone ! (gmail + contacts)

Tags: iphone, ios, accounts, google

I have an iPhone SE on old iOS 10.3.1 and I dont want to update it.

How do I add a Google account? This doesn't work:

There is a web popup (I can enter email + password, password is valid) but after that nothing happens.

No email account is added and I no longer have my contacts on my iPhone SE!
Is Google blocking old version of iOS ?

[image]